# Which ML algorithm, architecture and packages could be used for 3D sequence data with 4D-5D output?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, regression, sequence, recurrent-neural-network

I want to train a model on FEM simulations and predict the deformations and the stresses.

So, the **input** is the geometry (~100k nodes with x, y, z dimensions) and the "master node", where the strain is applied (boundary conditions). What changes through the different cases is the geometry (number and location of the nodes) and the master node. The strain applied is the same.

The **output** is the dx, dy, dz deformations of each node and the stress that it takes, namely the output is a ~100k x 4 matrix. An idea would be to train 2 different models, one for the deformations and the other for the stresses...

Any suggestions on which algorithm and architecture could be suitable? The data seems to be sequential, because the deformation is passed from node to node, but everything that I found was on NLP, where the information travels 1D. Is there any way to apply Recurrent NN in 3D data and is it relative to this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: You just have multiple input features and multiple outputs, but you still have a 1D sequence (time), so you can use basically any algorithm for predicting sequential data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I only have initial and final positions of the nodes, without the intermediate time steps

Comment: Then it's a simple regression problem.

Comment: I came across with the idea that everything can be done with simple regression/classification, but regarding the type of the data, other algorithms can be much more efficient (e.g. ConvNets on images). I thought maybe this is the case with this data, because it is not some standard regression input-output.

Comment: Also, the number of features (if the dimentions of the nodes are considered as features) are always different, as well as the number of the output is always different (relative with the number of inputs).